# SQL server: How do I combine my rows distinctly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

my data from my table is:

```
**country       2010    2011     2012**
Argentina   NULL    NULL    true
Argentina   NULL    true    NULL
Argentina   true    NULL    NULL
Bolivia     NULL    NULL    true
Bolivia     NULL    true    NULL
Bolivia     NULL    NULL    NULL
Canada      NULL    NULL    true
Canada      NULL    NULL    NULL
Canada      true    NULL    NULL
```

what I want is to remove the "NULLS" and combine the "true" in the data so that it looks like:

```
**country       2010    2011     2012**
Argentina   true    true    true
Bolivia     NULL    true    true
Canada      true    NULL    true
```

Im thinking that I would have to use self joins for this or even perhaps case statements, but I am unsure where to start.

Comment: What data type is `true`?

Comment: NULL/TRUE are the only two values?

Comment: yes. null/true are the only two

Comment: Seriously consider redesigning your schema.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using `max()` with aggregation:

```
select country, max(`2010`) as `2010`, max(`2011`) as `2011`, max(`2012`) as 2012
from t
group by country;
```